# Quantum Chemistry book recommendation.

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, quantum-mechanics, chemistry

I am trying to learn quantum chemistry. I have an extensive background in math and physics, so I'm looking for a book that makes full use of whatever physics and mathematics is relevant to this subject, although I'm not sure if such a text even exists.

I am familiar with all the math and physics one might need, including functional analysis, quantum mechanics, relativity, differential geometry, etc. I am a math PhD student. I also have a degree in physics.

Perhaps I should also explain that quantum chemistry is a highly mathematical subject, that involves topics in math such as differential equations and perturbation theory. I ask this question here because I am interested in a book that makes full use of whatever mathematical tools the study of quantum chemistry might benefit from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is manifestly not a mathematics question.

Comment: wouldn't this be a better question for chemistry stack exchange?

Comment: Also, your question is missing a ton of information, like what your level is...

Comment: There are many requests on this site for textbook recommendations on non-mathematical subjects, like economics. As for my level, like I said you can assume I'm familiar with all the relevant math and physics. I'm familiar with QM, SR, GR, functional analysis, rigged Hilbert spaces, algebraic topology etc. etc. etc. I am a PhD student in math and have a degree in physics. I'm posting this on the math stackexchange for the same reason many people ask for textbook recommendations here, because they want a book that makes full use of math. Books aimed at non-mathematicians generally fail to do so.

Comment: For example, there are many posts on this site asking for recommendations for books on quantum mechanics, general relativity, etc. Why are those posts not closed? @user296602

Comment: @golingonner I personally think that academia.stackexchange.com might be a more suitable website to search.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan No, this question would be very far from the scope of academia SE.

Comment: @user296602 I personally don't know about that but it may be _better_ received there than here in math SE.

Comment: @user296602 can you explain why my post is manifestly not a mathematics question but these other ones are?

Comment: [Szabo and Ostlund](https://www.amazon.com/Modern-Quantum-Chemistry-Introduction-Electronic/dp/0486691861) is a classic that everyone interested in Quantum Chemistry should be aware of. By the way, similar questions such as [Quantum mechanical books for mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348939/quantum-mechanical-books-for-mathematicians?noredirect=1&lq=1) have been received well on this forum. Another example of a question in this spirit is [(Organic) Chemistry for Mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47177/organic-chemistry-for-mathematicians?rq=1).

Comment: @golingonner If you disagree and think this is on-topic, so be it; I'm only a single user who thinks it's off-topic. I would, however, very much appreciate it if you would stop pinging me about this, and not edit your post with a bunch of fluff about how it isn't off-topic.

Comment: @user296602 that "fluff" seems to be needed to demonstrate that my question is consistent with the sort of questions that are routinely asked on this  site. I really don't understand the issue with my question, frankly. Perhaps I should have explained that QC is a highly mathematical subject, much like QM.

Comment: We have a small list: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/4945 @qbert It would be closed with that target.

Comment: @golingonner As I explained for another user [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/100745/67043) you should read _Computational Quantum Chemistry: A primer_ by E Cances, Defranceschi, Kutzelnigg, Le Bris and Maday. Also you should look at other articles of the same issue.